# Consistency guarantees of Kubernetes ConfigMaps?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

Trying to decide where to store some critical sharding configs, and I have not yet found sufficient documentation around the reliability of Kube ConfigMaps to ease my mind.

Say I have a single-cluster kube pod spec that injects an environment variable with the value of a configmap entry at pod start (using [configMapKeyRef](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data)). I have many pods running based on this spec.

1. I `kubectl edit` the configmap entry and wait for the operation to succeed.
2. I restart the pods.

Are these pods guaranteed to see the new configmap value? (Or, failing that, is there a window of time I'd need to wait before restarting the pods to ensure that they get the new value?)

Similarly, are all pods guaranteed to see a consistent value, assuming there are no configmap edits during the time they are all restarting?

Answer (score 4):

Kubernetes is an eventual consistency system. It is [recommended](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/configGeneration.md) to *create a new ConfigMap* when you want to change the value.

> Changing the data held by a live configMap in a cluster is considered bad practice. Deployments have no means to know that the configMaps they refer to have changed, so such updates have no effect.

Using [Declarative config management with Kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/), this is easier to do using [configMapGenerator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#configmapgenerator)

> The recommended way to change a deployment's configuration is to
>
> 1. create a new configMap with a new name,
> 2. patch the deployment, modifying the name value of the appropriate configMapKeyRef field.

**Deployment**

When using Kustomize for both `Deployment` and `ConfigMap` using the *configMapGenerator* the name of `ConfigMap` will be generated based on content and the references to the `ConfigMap` in `Deployment` will be updated with the generated name, so that a new *rolling deployment* will be triggered.

Comment: Thanks - but I am not using Kustomize. I acknowledge that I will need to reroll the pods to get them to pick up the new config. I am wondering about the basic behavior between kubelet and configmap fetching.

Comment: It is _eventual consitency_ and there is no way to find out.

Comment: I recommend to use `kubectl apply -k <files>` and keep your _files_ in Git repository.